# Where does "to make out" come from?

Tags: phrase-origin

Is there any logical explanation for how the phrase *making out* came together?

I know that it has sexual implications (at least *kissing*, with the intent go further), I just can't imagine its ancestry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Make out* has been used with a sexual meaning since 1939.

The third edition of the NOAD reports the meaning of *make out* is, informally, "engage in sexual activity", "make progress", and "fare".

Comment: It's actually slightly more specific than that nowadays. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Making_out

Comment: As an 11k user I'm quite sure you know this, but my inner pedant would like to point out that *on 1939* is incorrect. It would be clearer to say *It was first used with this meaning in 1939*.

Comment: I guess that means a fully logical explanation of the phrase does not really exist. Too bad.

Comment: @Tomalek: If you don't get an answer to your question, you don't have to click 'accept' on whatever exists; you can wait until you get one. :-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: I know pretty well how these sites [work](http://stackoverflow.com/users/18771/tomalak). :) However, I had a feeling that it would not get much better than this. Some phrases just cannot be fully explained.

Answer (score 0):

According  to  Merriam-webster 
Under the 24th article for the word "Make" it states: 《24 : to persuade to consent to sexual intercourse : SEDUCE》
  And like most of the explanations agree it usually refers to preteens and teenagers, 
 And that type of behavior was typically done while away from home or "Out"
  Maybe "out" on a date . 
    When put together you have "Make-Out"

Comment: In contrast to the accepted answer, this actually gets a little bit closer to the "logical explanation" requested by the OP. It goes one step further.